# How to combine multiple getServerSideProps wrappers?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I'm using two libraries in my NextJs app: `next-firebase-auth` and `next-redux-wrapper`. Both of them require me to wrap `getServerSideProps` with their respective functions.

For `next-firebase-auth`

```
export const getServerSideProps = withAuthUserSSR()(async ({ AuthUser }) => {
    // Some code
})
```

For `next-redux-wrapper`

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    ({store}) => {
        // Some code
    }
);
```

Both work individually but I was unable to get the two working simultaneously. NextJs only allows `getServerSideProps` to be declared once. Is it possible to somehow combine multiple wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the wrappers one after the other. The inner function will contain the additional props passed by both of them.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = withAuthUserSSR()(wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    ({ AuthUser, store, res, req }) => {
        // `getServerSideProps` code here
    }
))
```

---

From `next-redux-wrapper` v7, the `wrapper.getServerSideProps` signature has changed.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = withAuthUserSSR()(wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    (store) => async ({ AuthUser, res, req }) => {
        // `getServerSideProps` code here
    }
))
```